# Reflections of Graphs?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, reflection

When I reflect a function over the $y$ axis:

$$f(-x)$$

Consider the function $f(x+3)$. When reflecting this over the y axis:

$$f(-x+3)$$

I cannot intuitively understand why the reflection is not $f(-x-3)$? Why do we only change the sign of $x$ and not the $3$. I'm extremely confused.

Could someone explain intuitively how reflections of functions work?

Comment: See whether [Graph transformations](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4515476/21813) sheds any light.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For any function $g(x) = \text{ expression}$, you evaluate $g(1)$ by *replacing* $x$ with $1$ in the $\text{ expression}$. You can do this for any number instead of $1$. 
Suppose I say $\text{ expression} = f(x+3)$. So, $g(x) = f(x+3)$. The reflection of $g(x)$ is the same as the reflection of $f(x+3)$. Reflection of $g(x)$ over the $y$-axis is $g(-x)$. Now, replace $x$ with $-x$ in the $\text{ expression}$ to find $g(-x)$ in terms of $f$. We get $g(\color{blue}{-x}) = f(\color{blue}{-x}+3)$. That's your answer.

Comment: [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/951667/1088689) by [EWH Lee](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/170579/e-w-h-lee) may be useful too, though it only considers a specific function.